# Spring Data Jpa Test with H2 and restored backup from MSSQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, h2

I was wondering is it possible to restore MSSQL server backup on H2 database during spring data jpa test.
H2 has compatible mode MSSQL, but then I cannot run it as in-memory db. So is possible?

Comment: I would say no. Unless the backup is in ANSI SQL format and doesn't use any customized SQL it **might** work. But I highly doubt it would.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for response